# How can I align label of a button component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a button component on my scene. But when I set labelPlacement to left, it can't do that. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand and have read about the `labelPlacement` property is that it works in conjunction with the use of an icon within the button, not to necessarily change the position of the text in relation to the button boundary.

Here is some text that documents this from the Adobe Website:

> If you are using an icon with a Button instance, you can control the placement of the text label, relative to the icon, by setting the labelPlacement property using one of the constants from the ButtonLabelPlacement class (fl.controls.ButtonLabelPlacement). For more information on working with button icons, see Setting icons.

Source: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/button_component_as3.html
Additional sources: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/button_component_as3.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_6

---

However, a hackish way of moving the text to the left would be to add spaces to the right of the string.  Currently, empty spaces at the start or end of the label are not auto trimmed.  Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
import fl.controls.Button;

var myButton:Button = new Button();
myButton.label = "Click me              ";

addChild(myButton);
```

I tested the code shown above in Flash CC 2014 and the text *looked* like it was left aligned, when it really wasn't because of the additional spaces added to the end of label.

It is worth mentioning that I also experiemented with the `textField` property of the `Button` class to see if the `autoSize` or `setTextFormat` functionality could be used to left align the text, and those all failed.